# QT and custom menu item (QLineEdit)

Tags: qt, qt4

How can I use QLineEdit as a menu item in QMenu? Is there any solutions to do this?

Just to do something like this (look at the edit box under the avatar):

[image]

Comment: If not a secret, for what porpoise you need such a "realization"?

Comment: status change for social network

Comment: Is this social network client on Linux or Mac? If Linux, you may find the source code, and use them as the start point, of how to place LineEdit to Menu...

Comment: this client is based on gtk, but I need qt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a [QWidgetAction](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qwidgetaction.html) to contain your QLineEdit. It inherits QAction.

Comment: Wow, thank you. Seems like it exactly what I need.
I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [QComboBox](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qcombobox.html). It allows editing of items in a pop-up menu. But if you mean the menu in the main menu bar, I don't think there's a way to do it. And it's not a good UI anyway.

Comment: I've attached a picture in my question. I need something like this - editbox in popup menu.